# Is there a way to bypass resistance/immunity to fire damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage-resistance, damage-types, immunities

I want to use fire-based spells for thematic reasons and a lot of things have immunity to it.

Is there a feat or class feature I could use to bypass/reduce those? For example, is there something that ignores fire resistance and reduces fire immunity to just resistance?

I know the easy way around it is just to pick another damage type spell but I really want to roleplay a pyromancer/firebender-type character.

Comment: Just steal from inn some barrels with oil, or other easy flamable things from alchemist's shop and use telekinesis spells to cover the immune enemy and fire the oil. That way you'll brute force your way through resistance. And that's cool :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### You have a few not very good options for overcoming resistance, and only one option for overcoming immunity, albeit drawn from "unofficial" content.

**Your best option is probably the Elemental Adept feat, as it is "permanent".**
But it only overcomes resistance, not immunity. This is probably the only really viable option in the rules as written, and it's not great, but it does best fit your character's needs.

**So far, the only way to overcome immunity is the Pyromancer.**

*Note: Even though this is published by Wizards, it is unofficial content, meaning it is not vetted at the same level as official content.*

The Pyromancer is a sorcerer from a [Planeshift Pdf](https://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/magic/Plane-Shift_Kaladesh.pdf) detailing the Magic:The Gathering setting of Kaladesh for use in 5e.  At 18th level, they gain the following:

> **Fiery Soul**
>
> At 18th level, you gain immunity to fire damage. In addition, any
> spell or effect you create ignores resistance to fire damage and
> treats immunity to fire damage as resistance to fire damage.

### Other options

- There is the [*Elemental Bane*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/elemental-bane) spell.  But that only covers resistance, requires a save and is concentration.  Not a good option.
- You can also look to spells abilities and items that grant [vulnerability](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/02/16/tomb-of-levistus-would-existing-resistance-to-fire-be-negated-by-the-vulnerability-to-fire/), as this is pretty close to the same as eliminating resistance (but again, [it does nothing to immunity](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/03/21/contagion-spell-flesh-rot-cancels-immunities-to-damage-of-the-creature/)).  Spells like [*Hallow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow) and [*Contagion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Contagion) (flesh rot option) do this.  Or *Channel Divinity: Path to the Grave* from a [*Grave Domain* Cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#GraveDomain).
- Any other ability I found is related to switching out the damage type, ala the [*Order of Scribes* Wizard Subclass](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#OrderofScribes), which is not exactly what you want.  Although, technically it does effectively bypass immunity to a given damage type.  Check under the *Awakened Spellbook* feature.
- Along those lines, in *Tasha's Cauldron Of Everything*
  there is a sorcerer metamagic option called [*Transmute Spell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#OptionalClassFeatures) (remember any spellcaster can now get [metamagic using feats](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/metamagic-adept)) which reads

> When you cast a spell that deals a type of damage from the following list, you can spend 1 sorcery point to change that damage type to one of the other listed types: acid, cold, fire, lightning, poison, thunder.

Comment: With a wink-and-a-nod from the DM, you could use the Lore Wizard to change the damage type to, say, Radiant, but describe the effect as being otherwise indistinguishable from Fire.

Comment: Your idea list seems somewhat complete, would like to add to it with the pyromancer sorcerous origin's 18th level ability. http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/sorcerer:pyromancy .
"At 18th level, you gain immunity to fire damage. In addition, any spell or effect you create ignores resistance to fire damage and treats immunity to fire damage as resistance to fire damage."

Comment: @Justin Added.  Thanks

Comment: You should note that the Pyromancer *is not official content*, despite being published by Wizards.

Comment: @Thomas-Markov Done Thanks

Comment: @JWT That's a way better note than I was thinking of, nice work.

Comment: "granting vulnerability... is pretty close to the same as eliminating resistance" - I don't agree with that analysis.  After you've inflicted vulnerability, a target that had resistance will *still* be taking half the damage they would do if they didn't have resistance - so you still have exactly the same incentive to remove that resistance somehow.

Comment: @andrzej-doyle Of course taking two actions/feats/spell will net you more than taking just one.  But comparing spending two resources to only one doesn't make much sense from an analysis standpoint.  Of course it will be better.  Bottom line: A spell that removes resistance is within one point of damage in its affect as a spell that gives the target vulnerability.

Answer (score 22):

## The Elemental Adept feat can beat resistance.

The Elemental Adept feat (PHB 166) says:

> When you gain this feat, choose one of the following damage types: cold, fire, lightning, or thunder. Spells you cast ignore resistance to damage of the chosen type.

This allows you to bypass resistance. However, as far as I know, after looking through both the DMG and PHB, there is no spell or spellcasting ability that "beats" immunity, or changes immunity to resistance.

Answer (score 17):

In the [Plane Shift: Kaladesh pdf](http://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/magic/Plane-Shift_Kaladesh.pdf) there is a pyromancer subclass for sorcerer.
On page 9 in the bottom right. It has several abilities that are relevant.

Starting at level 6, all your spells ignore fire resistance.

> **Fire in the Veins** At 6th level, you gain resistance to fire damage. In
>   addition, spells  you cast ignore resistance to fire damage.

At level 18, all abilities you use ignore fire resistance and treats immunity as resistance.

> **Fiery Soul**
>   At 18th level, you gain immunity to fire damage. In addition, any 
>   spell or effect you create ignores resistance to fire damage and 
>   treats immunity to fire damage as resistance to fire damage.

Comment: this is the most correct answer, and the only one that literally bypasses immunity.

Comment: What sucks is although you can hurt resisted creatures at 6th, you have to wait until the end of your campaign to hurt the immune ones.  You may want to talk to your DM, but if it fit your character thematically, and by RAW it should work, at 19th level for your ASI/Feat, take Elemental Adept, choosing Fire, so the now immune-turned-resistance, would now take full damage.  You took it after they were converted to resistant, so it would specifically be to learn how to overcome this "new fire resistance".  So by 19th level you can finally have the full version of the character you want.