# Are there any spells or magic items that allow a user to bypass fire resistance?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, damage-resistance

A bit of a specific request I know, but for an upcoming battle my DM is throwing at us, I'll be using a magical weapon that deals fire damage and we know the creature has fire resistance. So I was wondering if there were any options to ignore the opponent's fire resistance. I know of the Elemental Bane spell already, but if there were any other spells that had this effect as well that would be helpful to know as well.

Comment: At least related (dupe?): [Is there a way to bypass resistance/immunity to fire damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103123/52137)